# estimation of the difference between two step functions by 1/sqrt(n)

Tags: calculus, integration, estimation

Given are $ g_n ~and~ k_n$ two step functions, such that for $f\geq0$, which is Riemann-integrable the following holds: $0\leq{g_n}\leq{f}\leq{k_n}$
We diefined Riemann's integrability of $f$ in our lecture as a function, having such a property:
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are 2 step functions $ g_n ~and~ k_n$ (as given above) such that:

$\int_a^b \! (k_n(x)-g_n(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x<1/n$

Now we defined $h(x):=\sqrt{g_n(x)+1/n}-1/n$ and $s(x):=\sqrt{k_n(x)+1/n}$

I was able to prove, that $h(x)\leq{\sqrt{f}}\leq{s(x)}$

AND HERE IS MY QUESTION:

I want to prove, that:
$\int_a^b \! (s(x)-h(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x<(b-a+1)\sqrt{n}$

I have tried to work with the integrand by using one of the bonominal formulas, but then I just came to a conclusion, that:

$\int_a^b \! (s(x)-h(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x\leq\int_a^b \! ((\sqrt{s(x)}-\sqrt{h(x)}+\sqrt{1/n}) \, \mathrm{d}x$
 Now here I do not know, how to move further.
Thank you

EDIT:

I made a bit more and figured out, that I have to prove this inequality:

$\int_a^b \! \frac{k_n(x)-g_n(x)}{\sqrt{k_n(x)+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{g_n(x)+\frac{1}{n}}} \, \mathrm{d}x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

But I see no way at the moment how to move on.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Since the functions $g_n$ and $k_n$ are non-negative, we have 
$$\sqrt{k_n(x)+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{g_n(x)+\frac{1}{n}}\ge 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
Hence
$$\int_a^b \! \frac{k_n(x)-g_n(x)}{\sqrt{k_n(x)+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{g_n(x)+\frac{1}{n}}} \, dx\le$$ 
$$\int_a^b \! \frac{k_n(x)-g_n(x)}{2\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}dx=$$ $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\int_a^b \! (k_n(x)-g_n(x)) \,dx<
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\frac 1n=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the last equality be $= 1/(2\sqrt{n})$ ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Oops.Corrected.Thanks.